# Application to Application Notifications

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I am creating a Taxi App in which I have a driver application and a user application. When a user posts a request for a ride, ALL drivers must be notified that a request is available (Push Notifications). How can my native code know when to send notification?m

I don't want the Application to be Battery and Data Hungry, so I can't run a check over my MySQL database every minute. I looked for a solution with **Firebase**, but found out that they provide service for web to android notifications. I haven't written any code related to that yet.

Please suggest a way to achieve this. Googling it didn't help. If possible, attach code.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: for the starter , check `Firebase Functions`

Comment: @AbdulKawee This seems to be lengthy process and I need to update it in the next hour. Thanks for early reply. It is definitely useful and I will implement if other options are not available. Till then +1

Comment: if you have knowledge of backend languages like `PHP` you can make your own api, which will send notification to the users, but if you are using `firebase` as a whole then `Functions` are good

Comment: @AbdulKawee I am a beginner in PHP so can't code well by myself. Only good at amendments. If you have some code available, please post it.

Comment: okay i will try to explain you a bit, posting code below with example links also

Comment: please check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `firebase` is not that difficult to use, here is the code for your `PHP Api`

```
// function makes curl request to firebase servers
private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

    require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

And now what **config.php** has is

```
<?php

// Firebase API Key
define('FIREBASE_API_KEY', '///lGrYwgBC8iz5reyx4qPUB7ByXX8MwC7Vcs8u...');
     ?>
```

You can get this key from `Firebase Console` under **Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Server Key**

and now one simple function to send push notification

```
public function send($to, $message) {
    $fields = array(
        'to' => $to,
        'data' => $message,
    );
    return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
}
```

Here in `$to` will come the Notification Id of the person you want to send notification. Here is the [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

Hope this helps you